# Is it possible to easily calculate a weapon's DPS In Darksiders 2?

Tags: darksiders-2

I was trying to do a little mathomancy earlier and calculate the DPS for my current weapon. However, I noticed that there isn't a defined statistic for attack speed in the game, only a single word describing a weapon's attack speed (Slow, Fast, etc). Does this mean it is not possible to easily calculate an item's DPS, or does the game have some sort of built in way of showing/determining DPS?

I did notice the game showing me a Mace's weapon damage in red when the damage was significantly higher than the weapon damage of the Fists I was using. This may suggest that the game also considers attack speed when checking if a weapon is an upgrade for the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up your inventory and press Toggle Stats (X on an Xbox Controller), it displays the DPS for your current primary and secondary weapons in the pane in the bottom right corner.